# REST API: admin routes, /entity/admin or /admin/entity?

Tags: api, rest, api-design, separation-of-concerns, cross-cutting-concerns

Implementing a RESTful API, and have setup a file structure like so:

```
|-- api
    `-- entity
        |-- models.d.ts
        |-- models.ts
        `-- routes.ts
```

Admin/sudo routes could go in `api/admin/entity_name.ts` or `api/entity/admin.ts`.

Former is useful because all admin controls are in one place, easier to audit, standardise, turn off all admin access &etc. Latter is handy because it's very close to the "normal user" implementation.

Which option is best?

Comment: These admin routes are specifically for batch processing—e.g.: show me all users, add role `x` to all users—rather than simply about admin access on a per entity basis, which would be better handled by adding all logic in the `edit_one_user` route, only allowing admins to edit users other than themselves.